# Problem with the AMD drivers in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati, radeon

After installing the driver for the video card ATI Radeon HD 3870, I can not run Ubuntu (just a purple screen and all). Tried to go to recovery mode as root and write "apt-get purge fglrx*", but nothing happened. Then I decided to go into failsafe mode, but nothing (writes "clean some blocks" and all).

-Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (kernel 3.3.6)
-ATI Radeon HD 3870

*P.S. Sorry if I write with mistakes. I am Russian, and understand very little English, so I used Google*

Comment: Well, I was able to remove the driver in recovery mode. I did as follows: recovery mode -> resume -> sudo apt-get purge fglrx* && sudo apt-get autoremove. Done! Ubuntu now works. Thanks for the tip about AMD Wiki :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with ATI drivers is an art more than a science. I can't help you with your specific issue but in my opinion the best source of info is the [Unofficial ATI wiki](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page). There you will find not only specific Ubuntu-related info, it is also organised according to distribution and includes Precise Pangolin specific info [here](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Precise_Installation_Guide). While it might initially seem like a lot  of information, it's worth taking to understand how you need to interact with these drivers in order to get the most satisfying settings for your PC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all Skuyall welcome to askubuntu. To help you first you need to clean out the old AMD drivers properly and do not worry about your English. It is very clear.

First in a terminal (ctrl-alt-t) type the following

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle
```

This will completely remove all the fglrx drivers and your system will only then the open source drivers.

As Simon has said already there are some good wikis for ATI/AMD hardware and here on askubuntu there is a very good guide also

[Ask Ubuntu ATI Wiki](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/129200#129200)

Either this or the AMD linux page will help you to reinstall the drivers correctly if you need them from ATI or maybe you will choose not to but at least you will have the choice.

Let us know how you get on.